# Modularizing Multer Functionality Issue

Tags: node.js, express, module, multer

I am trying to clean up my controllers by modularizing my `multer` module functions, which allow me to upload multiple files with my forms. The current code presented below works, but I want put the multer function in a new file. I assumed that simply taking the function and exporting it from another file would work, but for some reason I'm hitting a time out during my form POST, despite calling the `console.log` at the start of the `multer` code. It appears that something within that code is stopping the process, but no error message is thrown. Does anyone see what might be causing the error?

**Multer called within route file:**

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var multer = require('multer');
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
var moment = require('moment');

var uploadDate = new moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
var s3 = new aws.S3();
var options = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
    Expires: 60
};

if(app.get('env') === 'production' || app.get('env') === 'staging'){
    options.ACL = 'private'
} else {
    options.ACL = 'public-read'
};

//////////Multer code being called

var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: options.Bucket,
        contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
        acl: options.ACL,
        key: function(req, file, cb){
            var fileNameFormatted = file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
            cb(null, req.session.organizationId + '/' + uploadDate + '/' + fileNameFormatted);
        }
    }),
    fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
        if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|csv|xls|xlsb|xlsm|xlsx)$/)){
            return cb('One of your selected files is not supported', false);
        }
        cb(null, true);
    }
}).array('fileUpload', 5);

///////Post route calling multer and rest of form submission

.post(function(req, res){

     upload(req, res, function(){
        if(err){
            console.log('Multer upload error');
            req.flash('error', err);
            res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
            return;
        }

        ... MORE CODE ...
    })
});
```

**/controllers/multer.js, which contains the multer code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var multer = require('multer');
var multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
var moment = require('moment');

var s3 = new aws.S3();
var uploadDate = new moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

var options = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
    Expires: 60,
    //ContentType: req.query.file_type
};

if(app.get('env') === 'production' || app.get('env') === 'staging'){
    options.ACL = 'private'
} else {
    options.ACL = 'public-read'
};

module.exports = {

    //Annotation file upload
    annotationFileUpload: function(){
        multer({
            storage: multerS3({
                s3: s3,
                bucket: options.Bucket,
                contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
                acl: options.ACL,
                key: function(req, file, cb){
                    console.log("key called");
                    var fileNameFormatted = file.originalname.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
                    cb(null, req.session.organizationId + '/' + uploadDate + '/' + fileNameFormatted);
                }
            }),
            fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
                console.log("file filter called");
                if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|csv|xls|xlsb|xlsm|xlsx)$/)){
                    return cb('One of your selected files is not supported', false);
                }
                cb(null, true);
            }
        }).array('fileUpload', 5);
    }
}
```

**Importing `/controller/multer` and calling route:**

```
var multerFile = require('./components/multer');

    .post(function(req, res){

    multerFile.annotationFileUpload(req, res, function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log('Multer upload error');
                    req.flash('error', err);
                    res.redirect(req.get('referer'));
                    return;
                }
           ....MORE CODE....
         })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the wrapper function, since `multer()` returns the middleware function itself. The reason it times out is because you're calling a function that just creates the middleware and immediately discards it and then does nothing else (like responding to the request).

So change this:

```
annotationFileUpload: function(){
    multer({
       // ...
    }).array('fileUpload', 5);
}
```

to this:

```
annotationFileUpload: multer({
  // ...
}).array('fileUpload', 5)
```

Comment: Thanks for that great catch @mscdex! I appreciate it!